# How to send PCL5 commands to Brother HL-1111 printer via USB?

Tags: c++, printing, usb, printer-control-language, usb-hostcontroller

I am trying to interface USB Printer (Brother HL-1111 series printer) using Vincullum -II Host Controller IC . I am able to enumerate the printer via USB port of controller but when I send PCL5 commands or any text to Printer , it is not able to print anything.

The enumeration status is shown in below image.
[image]

I send text to printer using below API,

```
// devCaps1 contains some String
if (vos_dev_write(hPrinter,(unsigned char *)devCaps1 , 10 , NULL) == USBHOSTPRINTER_OK)
    {
         //Print this status to serial terminal
        message("Check Printer Output\r\n");
    }
```

I send commands for Printer using below API,

```
//Esc(3@    or  (27)(40)(51)(64)[Decimal]  or    <1Bh><28h><33h><40h>[Hex]  For selecting default Font
//uint8 vos_dev_write(VOS_HANDLE h,uint8 *buf,uint16 num_to_write,uint16 *num_written);
//h - is for handle
    vos_dev_write(hPrinter,(char) 27 , 1 , NULL);
    vos_dev_write(hPrinter,(char) 40 , 1 , NULL);
    vos_dev_write(hPrinter,(char) 51 , 1 , NULL);
    vos_dev_write(hPrinter,(char) 64 , 1 , NULL);
```

So, Please Guide me to execute commands via USB.

Am i going in correct way or wrong way?